# Following Blender Tutorial gone wrong

Tags: modeling

I'm very new to Blender and modelling in general, so i was following this tutorial on how to make a Low Poly Character (https://youtu.be/Ljl_QFs9xhE?t=607), at 10:04 he extrudes the vertices down and then scales it inwards to make the shape of a waist, but when i do it, the mirrored parts separate like this:

[image: Scaling along the x-axis]

What am i doing wrong here? I'd appreciate very much if someone could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your mirror modifier, turn on "Clipping";

[image]

When you do, any virt that touches the center won't go beyond it (through the bound of the middle of the model, determined by the origin of the object), and those verts will also "stick" to the center (so you don't rip your model apart when moving or scaling)

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved it!

Comment: Awesome :D Make sure to mark an answer as the Accepted Answer for future users :)

Answer (score 1):

He is scaling in on the X-axis only. Are you sure you are doing the same?

Try hitting <kbd>S</kbd> , then hit <kbd>X</kbd> before you scale inward and that should create the same effect